# Can I use 7.5VDC @ 1.0A on 6V @ 2.0A device?

Tags: adapter, voltage

Just what the title asks....

- Can I use 7.5VDC @ 1.0A on 6V @ 2.0A device?

Anyone know the answer?

Comment: Sorry little typo - that's 6VDC @ 2.0A device...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laptop power supplies, does current matter?](http://superuser.com/questions/247312/laptop-power-supplies-does-current-matter)

Comment: Too much voltage and too little current.  Might work, might catch fire, might just sit there like a lump.

Answer (score 3):

Watts = volts X amps. One supplies 7.5 watts the other 12 watts.

Reinforcing the previous answer: No.

Comment: By that logic he could power his device with a 24V 500mA supply. :)

Comment: It's not exactly logic, it's just how electricity works. Obviously large deviations in voltage can't be made up for by more or less current. But to even have a chance the watts need to be at least close if not match. My statement was meant to depict the fact that the power adapter is incapable of supplying enough power for his application. At that point volts are moot. Your theoretical power adapter has enough power capability, but would likely not work due to the large deviation in voltage.

Comment: This site is not intended for playful jesting, people come here for answers. I also did not mean theoretical in the context that it doesn't exist, i have 24 volt power supplies at my office in varying amp outputs, the context was theoretical in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

No. The supply would not be able to provide enough current and would likely overheat.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this from a voltage rather than power standpoint the answer is either "No" or "Maybe, but you shouldn't".

It depends on what kind of power converter is in the device you are trying to power and whether it has a hard limit of 6V or supports a voltage range.  The current is only relevant to how "well" your device deals with not getting enough power.

If your device only takes 6-6.5V then using a 7.5V supply could well destroy the circuitry in the device and make it unusable.

If your device has a well specced power converter inside then you may be okay to use it but the device may not be getting the full amount of power necessary to, say, charge batteries at full power or even power up if it needs more current.

Working out how we'll specced the power converter in your device is is not really our job, that's your manufacturers job and they likely chose that power supply for a reason.

You may or may not damage your device, but either way you're not using the right power supply for the job.