# Laptop power supply 16V 4.5VA instead of 20V 3.25VA

Tags: power-supply, lenovo-laptop

Can I use 16V 4.5VA IBM Laptop power supply for Lenovo Laptop instead of original one 20V 3.25VA power supply?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/36311/is-it-safe-to-use-a-power-supply-with-a-different-laptop?rq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/53645/how-can-i-tell-if-an-ac-adapter-is-compatible-with-my-laptop?lq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/423719/using-adapter-with-higher-output-voltage?lq=1,

Comment: [Can I use a power adapter with more current but lower voltage on another laptop?](http://superuser.com/questions/172257/can-i-use-a-power-adapter-with-more-current-but-lower-voltage-on-another-laptop?rq=1), [Laptop power supplies, does current matter?](http://superuser.com/questions/247312/laptop-power-supplies-does-current-matter?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

The old style IBM power supply has a smaller barrel, and no central pin on the laptop end. The new sort is fat, has a thinner wall for the plug and has a central pin.The two styles of power supplies are physically incompatible

This is the new style power supply connector

[image]

This is the old one

[image]

They very simply will not ever fit in each other. I believe this is intentional, and trying to do so will very likely end up badly. You'll have components getting less voltage than they're designed for, which might end up in anything from minor issues, to things dying. Lenovo obviously did *not* want folk using oldstyle IBM power supplies in the thinkpads they made.