# Watts When Charging Devices

Tags: power-supply, battery, usb-c

While battery technology is constantly developing and evolving and along with the the commonly accepted "best practice" where it comes to charging (Li-ion Batteries) something troubles me...

I understand that pretty much every big manufacturer says that there is no point in carefully planning charging's and running battery to certain points before charging because it causes much more frustration that the battery life one could eek out of it assuming it is done correctly. As such, you can and should charge your device when ever you want for as long or as short as you like the only no go is to not leave the device dead flat ever not even for a few hours.

Chargers now exist and are common which deliver 60w 90w even 140w and 200w. If I am charging a lower power device via usb-c such as a phone, smart watch or tablet which calls for a 5w, 12w or 20-30w power adapter will it cause any battery harm if I were to use a 90, 140, 200w power adapter or will the device and adapter self regulate? similar to a power supply where it will only draw what it needs to draw? or will this 'fast charging' damage the longevity and health of the battery in the device?

For arguments sake assume we are using high quality power adapters from reputable computer manufacturers and devices manufactured in the past 5 years. The most extreme circumstances charging a smart watch with a 140w adapter.

I have looked at a few related questions but none specifically answer where it comes to usb-c and high, [Low Power](https://superuser.com/questions/448016/lower-power-output-when-charging-devices-is-that-ok)

Comment: The wattage stated is the maximum it can deliver, not the power it always deliver. Electricity will use up power based on what it needs. A lightbulb will use more electricity than a LED bulb, so with LED, less power is drawn, and you don't need to replace your lamp socket for that. A computer PSU can be rated for 1200W, but the computer itself may only use up 400W. That's perfectly normal. Going above 1200W though, and the computer could crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Chargers now exist and are common which deliver 60w 90w even 140w and
> 200w. If I am charging a lower power device via usb-c such as a phone,
> smart watch or tablet which calls for a 5w, 12w or 20-30w power
> adapter will it cause any battery harm if I were to use a 90, 140,
> 200w power adapter or will the device and adapter self regulate?

In the description you post, the devices self - regulate.

Power is "pulled", not "pushed"

If your 200 Watt charger has the same voltage and plug polarity as the device you are charging, then the device will draw the correct current.

In real life, I use a 2.4A iClever Charger for my iPhone. The Apple charger is 1 Amp. This works fine because the iPhone draws only what it needs.

Device draw the power they need.  Chargers deliver the power needed and do not push more power than needed.