# Is it safe to connect a 10amp cable to my laptop brick if it came with 7amp

Tags: hardware-failure, power, cable

The standard figure-8 section of my power cable is broken, and it's marked as 7amp/125volt. I haven't been able to find any others marked for 7amp, so would it be safe to connect a similarly shaped cable marked for 10amp?

This is the type of head: http://www.kenable.co.uk/images/fig_8_plug.jpg

Comment: [related] http://superuser.com/questions/247312/laptop-power-supplies-does-current-matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As 10 amps is higher that 7 amps then yes, you will be fine.

The 10A is the "safe" current carrying capacity of the wires, i.e. they can carry 10A without overheating or causing a potential problem.  If one set of wires can carry more current than another set of wires then they are "better" and should, technically, be slightly safer.

If it were the other way and you were replacing a 7A plug with a 3 or 5A plug, then I would be slightly cautious.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if the rating was how much they transferred or how much they are able to. If the brick pulls the same amount regardless that's great.

Comment: The ratings are how much they can withstand before there is a chance of a fault occuring.  The power brick will draw the same amount of current regardless of what cable is attached so if it is fine with a 7A cable then a higher rated cable will be fine too.