# Using HP charger on a Dell Inspiron 15R laptop

Tags: battery, dell-inspiron, adapter, charger

My Dell Inspiron 15R 5521 charger was stolen from my University desk.

I have an old (about 4-5 years old) HP charger of my previous HP laptop.

The Dell laptop on the bottom says: 19.5V and 3.34A / 4.62A.

The HP charger says on Output: 18.5V and 3.5A, 65W.

The plug fits fine. After I plugged it in, the laptop works fine, but the battery is not charging. On the battery icon (bottom right) it currently says "Plugged in, not charging".

I have talked with Dell and they said it might pose a risk to the motherboard and that I should buy an original adapter from them.

Can I use it temporarily or is it risky? Any help?

Thanks!!

Comment: Verify the output voltage amperage is high enough and within specifications for the Dell.  Based on the listed specifications the Dell requires higher amerage then the HP charger supports.

Comment: There could also be a verification circuit in place.  Dell hardware typically includes a piece that checks to see if the attached charger is a Dell charger, and if not, will not allow the charger to charge the battery.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/53645/how-can-i-tell-if-an-ac-adapter-is-compatible-with-my-laptop?lq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/36311/is-it-safe-to-use-a-power-supply-with-a-different-laptop, http://superuser.com/questions/172257/can-i-use-a-power-adapter-with-more-current-but-lower-voltage-on-another-laptop, http://superuser.com/questions/247312/laptop-power-supplies-does-current-matter

Comment: Hello Rahmound and thanks for the reply. On the back of the Dell laptop it writes "3.34A / 4.62A". The HP charger says "3.5A".

Comment: Kruug, what you said about Dell is true, they have confirmed that over the phone as well.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage is less which is okay but the amperage is more which is not good for the Dell and yes it could damage your laptop.  I would stop using the HP charger.

You can find used Dell chargers on ebay for less than $20.00.  I recently purchased one for $15.00 with free shipping.  Be sure to look for one with the same specs as your Dell Laptop as Dell has made many different charger configurations over the years.

Good Day!

Comment: No, using an adapter that has a greater current **capacity** will not harm the device using it. Using an adapter with a higher or lower voltage will probably harm the device. These are not constant current devices, rather constant voltage and the boilerplate amperage ratings are maximum capacity.